# Persistent "? PackageName" after precompiling in pkg, despite successful "using PackageName"

Tags: debugging, julia, precompile, julia-pkg

I am trying to add a package from a github repository. I write

```
(@v1.7) pkg> registry add https://github.com/organization/registryname.git
(@v1.7) pkg> add PackageName
   Resolving package versions...
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Project.toml`
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.7/Manifest.toml`
Precompiling project...
  ? PackageName
```

So I try `julia> using PackageName` , after which pre-compiling is successful. But when I go back and try `pkg> add package-name`, I get the same question mark. What does question mark mean? And what is the correct way to debug it to find out what's wrong?

Comment: Is your package name literally `package-name`?  Does it have a hyphen in it?

Comment: It’s called IPFitting

Comment: I suggest you use the actual package names in the question just to avoid confusion. For eg., when you say "when I go back and try pkg> add package-name", do you mean the same package or a different package? Are you getting this on every package install? And what environment (as in REPL, Jupyter, etc.) are you running this on? This might be a display issue too.